# Conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert Y,Z]\vert Z]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

### Problem

When proving one result in the statistical learning theory course, the instructor uses
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert Y,Z]\vert Z]=\mathbb{E}[X\vert Z]
$$
but I am not sure why this is true.

### What I Have Done

I know I could do the following
$$
\mathbb{E}[X\vert Y]=\int xf_{X\vert Y}(x\vert y)dx
$$
But when $X$ becomes complicated like $\mathbb{E}[X\vert Y,Z]$ (sorry for the abuse of variable name), I do not know how to proceed.

Could someone help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: For me I think it's very related to $$ P(A \mid B) = P(A \mid B,C) P(B \mid C) + P(A \mid B,C^c) P(B \mid C^c) $$

Answer (score 4):

This is just a special case of the usual
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]]$$
except all expectations are taken under the conditional distribution given the event $Z=z$. If you are still unsure, take your favorite proof of the above equality and replace all PDFs/PMFs with the conditional distribution given $Z=z$.

Comment: but ,  $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y]]$$ is the Law of total expectation and proved by the tower property $$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert Y,Z]\vert Z]$$. .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation . Wikipedia say the law of total expectation is special case of tower property.

Answer (score 0):

by tower property

if $F_1 \subset F_2$ so $E(E(X|F_2)|F_1)=E(X|F_1)$

now

$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert Y,Z]\vert Z]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert \sigma (Y,Z)]\vert \sigma(Z)]$

$=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X\vert F_2]\vert F_1]=E(X|F_1)$

$=\mathbb{E}[X\vert \sigma(Z)]=\mathbb{E}[X\vert Z]$

since  $F_1=\sigma(Z) \subset F_2=\sigma (Y,Z)$

this proof valid for all type of random variable(continues,discrete and mixture). so you do not need any assumption about type of random variable.